# Call constructor and deploy with web3 and ropsten

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have created a test contract which has been compiled successfully and want to broadcast on ropsten test network using web3js. I have a metmask account which i am using. I would like to know `how can i call constructor of my contract and then broadcast on ropsten`. 
I did broadcast one of my contract without constructor and do have my transaction hash key which is `0xf7e5a8e93db9989b033b85323cdff713ba88b547ef64a544550e145961999aac` but i am getting a following error `Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]` and `Transaction has been reverted by the EVM` on console. `I would like to know also why i am getting this error after broadcast has been done`

```
    const fs = require('fs')
    var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
    const Web3 = require('web3')
    const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/KEY')


    deploy()

    function deploy () {
        const privateKey = 'PRIVATE_KEY'
        const account1 = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER'
        const privateKey1 = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex')

        const contractData = fs.readFileSync('../../build/contracts/Testcontract.json')
        const contract = JSON.parse(contractData)
        const byteCode = contract['bytecode']
        web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
            const txObject = {
                nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
                gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(100000),
                gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.004', 'gwei')),
                data: byteCode
            }

            let tx = new Tx(txObject, {'chain':'ropsten'})
            tx.sign(privateKey1)
            const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
            const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
                console.log('err: ', err, 'txHash: ', txHash)
            })
        })
}
```

My contract with constructor looks like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract Testcontract {
    string public senderName;
    string public receiverName;
    uint public transferAmount;

    constructor (string memory _sender, string memory _receiver, uint _amount) public {
        senderName = _sender;
        receiverName = _receiver;
        transferAmount = _amount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

A simple way to deploy a contract through an Infura node is using [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/overview). In your project's root directory

```
$ npm install truffle
$ truffle init
```

[Here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider) is a tutorial on how to configure Truffle to use your Infura project. In short, install Truffle's `hd-wallet-provider`

```
$ npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider
```

Replace `truffle-config.js` with

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const mnemonic = "orange apple banana...";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<YOUR INFURA PROJECT ID>'),
      network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
    },
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.11",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  }
}
```

The previous code configures Truffle to connect to Infura an use your account. In `./migrations` directory (created by `truffle init`) create a new file `2_deploy_testContrac.js` where you can define how to deploy your contract and provide the arguments needed by TestContract.

```js
var TestContract = artifacts.require("./TestContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(TestContract, "AliceSender", "BobSender", 120);
}
```

Finally, deploy your contract by executing

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

The reason why your transaction has been reverted is because the constructor of TestContract expected three arguments but you have given zero. Since the constructor couldn't be executed, your deploying transaction was reverted as well.

Instead of manually creating your deploying transaction, you can use [web3.eth.Contract.deploy](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-deploy). With this method you can conveniently provide all parameters required by the contract's constructor.

**UPDATE:** The solution below won't work with Infura because the Infura API does not expose `web3.eth.personal` functions and it only allows sending `rawTranscations`.

You should be able to deploy your contract with the following code. Note that it was mainly copy-pasted from the [official web3 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-contract.html#id24).

```js
var contractData = fs.readFileSync('../../build/contracts/Testcontract.json');
var contract = JSON.parse(contractData);
var abi = contract['abi'];
var bytecode = contract['bytecode'];

var testContract = eth3.eth.Contract(abi);

var account = ...;
var password = ...;
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account, password);

testContract.deploy({
    data: bytecode,
    arguments: ['SenderAlice', 'ReceiverBob', 120]
})
.send({
    from: account,
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '30000000000000'
}, function(error, transactionHash){ 
    console.log(error, transactionHash); 
})
.on('error', function(error){ 
    console.log(error);
})
.on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){
    console.log(transactionHash); 
})
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
   console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ 
    console.log(confirmationNumber, transactionHash); 
})
.then(function(newContractInstance){
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
});
```

Comment: I am getting following errors:1)The method personal_unlockAccount does not exist/is not available. 2)The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't notice you were trying to use Infura. I updated my response to cover that problem. As for your error messages: the problem was that the Infura API doesn't expose those functions. You can only send raw transactions as you tried, however to deploy a contract, the recommended way is through truffle.